# Limiting Text length to mx textarea available size in flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, textarea

I'm trying to build a dynamically sized mx textArea which limits the possible text to its size.

E.g the textarea is set to width="300" and height="100". Now the user should only be able to enter or paste as much text as can be visible in the component. I don't want the textArea to scroll or linebreak if more text is entered.

I tried all sorts of approaches, but none with success.

Help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is any direct property to achieve that, but you can try to set the maxChars with respect to the width of textarea on CreationComplete

```
private function adjustMaxChars(e:FlexEvent):void{
            var maxAllowedChars:int = (myTxt.width * 15) / 100;
            myTxt.maxChars = maxAllowedChars;
            trace('max chars allowed ', myTxt.maxChars);
        }
```

Above function set an average of 15 chars per 100px width, function is called on creationComplete. (change the number of chars per 100px to suit your need)

Comment: what to be done, if the text area has multiple lines? And also the font size of the text inside the textarea can be edited at run time, any other solution for this?